# tensorflow train a network and save as a function

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to train a network and then use this network as a feature extractor; so I want to save this one like a function.

I know how to save a trained model and to reuse the model I, but I want to use this trained model as part of my new graph just like a function, see structure below.

I guess I probably need to append the new graph to the old model graph and fixed old model' parameters. Can any one give me some ideas of how to do this? Thank you.

```
# define a graph and train a model called mdl in a session
# this mdl will be fixed used in the new graph 

# start a new graph
cae_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,a,b,1))
cae_out = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,a,b,1))

# use this model to process my input
loss = mdl(cae_in) - cae_out


with tf.Session() as sess:
  # run this sess
```

Answer (score 0):

I think do can follow these steps:

- You can probably create a TF or Keras model with required layers and hyperparameters. I insist to use TF Keras as it can save the model as a single `.h5` file.
- Once you have the model saved, create a new class named `mdl`, or even a method.
- Load the model in this method and feed the inputs ( given as arguments to the method ) to the model.
- Make an inference, process and reshape it and then return the output from the method.

**Hence, you can encapsulate the model in a method or class.**